# Where should I discharge my bathroom exhaust to?

Tags: bathroom, fan

Everyone in general lean towards roof or gable end of house venting. Then of these two whichever is shortest run..Also everyone agrees down hill slope toward exterior of house..If one is to vent through the roof no house could accomplish this. The slope would inevitably point back to the ceiling. My house has two baths on the front side of house..Currently they vent to the front side of soffit..If I vented them both to the Gable 18ft of pipe would be needed. If vented through the roof 13ft would be needed to get to the back side of the ridge vent..Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Before you run any type of vent you should find out when your house was built and see what was code at that time.  More recent building codes require a dedicated vent exiting the roof and there are restrictions about how close it can be to other vents or runs.  To avoid an expensive process of redoing this later, talk to your local code enforcment officer to find out what the right choice is.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. The conclusion I have come to is that the shortest available route that is horizontal is probably best if you have to take account of cold climate and that a solid pipe if possible is even better. You will need to note the distance spec of your fan and go for more power if necessary. 
If you have very cold winters you may have problems with steam condensing in a vertical pipe and dripping back into your bathroom. In any case the vent conduit should be covered with insulation.